# SQL Server Get Latest Rows From Table Joined to Another Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Needing a bit of a help here with an SQL Server query.

Pretty much, I need to display all the players with their corresponding latest status. I've devised my query as below, but one player who does not have any status is not showing up. I need for that player to be displayed on the list and his StatusDesc would simply be NULL.

As you can see from the final select query I have, I am missing a player (Ray Allen) who does not have a record in the PlayerStatus table.

The setup as follows:

```
/*Create the Temp Tables*/

CREATE TABLE #Player(
PlayerID int,
PlayerName varchar(50), 
PlayerTeam varchar(150));

CREATE TABLE #PlayerStatus(
PlayerStatusID int IDENTITY(1, 1),
PlayerID int,
StatusID int,
CreatedDate date);

CREATE TABLE #Status(
StatusID int,
StatusDesc varchar(20));

/* Populate Tables */
INSERT INTO #Player VALUES(1, 'Tim Duncan', 'Spurs');
INSERT INTO #Player VALUES(2, 'Tony Parker', 'Spurs');
INSERT INTO #Player VALUES(3, 'Manu Ginobili', 'Spurs');
INSERT INTO #Player VALUES(4, 'Boris Diaw', 'Spurs');
INSERT INTO #Player VALUES(5, 'Kawhi Leonard', 'Spurs');

INSERT INTO #Player VALUES(6, 'Lebron James', 'Heat');
INSERT INTO #Player VALUES(7, 'Dwayne Wade', 'Heat');
INSERT INTO #Player VALUES(8, 'Chris Bosh', 'Heat');
INSERT INTO #Player VALUES(9, 'Mario Chalmers', 'Heat');
INSERT INTO #Player VALUES(10, 'Udonis Haslem', 'Heat');
INSERT INTO #Player VALUES(11, 'Ray Allen', 'Heat');


INSERT INTO #PlayerStatus(PlayerID, StatusID, CreatedDate)
SELECT PlayerID, 1, GETDATE()
FROM #Player;

INSERT INTO #PlayerStatus(PlayerID, StatusID, CreatedDate)
VALUES(8, 4, GETDATE());

DELETE FROM #PlayerStatus WHERE PlayerID = 11;

INSERT INTO #Status(StatusID, StatusDesc)
VALUES(1, 'Healthy');

INSERT INTO #Status(StatusID, StatusDesc)
VALUES(2, 'Injured');

INSERT INTO #Status(StatusID, StatusDesc)
VALUES(3, 'Retired');

INSERT INTO #Status(StatusID, StatusDesc)
VALUES(4, 'Reserved');

--SELECT * FROM #Player;
--SELECT * FROM #PlayerStatus;
--SELECT * FROM #Status;

/* Select all Players and their Status */
SELECT ply.PlayerName, ply.PlayerTeam, sta.StatusDesc, pls.CreatedDate
FROM #PlayerStatus pls
INNER JOIN #Player ply ON ply.PlayerID = pls.PlayerID
INNER JOIN #Status sta ON pls.StatusID = sta.StatusID
LEFT JOIN #PlayerStatus pls2 ON pls2.PlayerID = pls.PlayerID AND pls2.PlayerStatusID > pls.PlayerStatusID
WHERE pls2.PlayerStatusID IS NULL
ORDER BY ply.PlayerID ASC;

DROP Table #Player;
DROP Table #PlayerStatus;
DROP Table #Status;
```

Hopefully someone can provide insight on how I would need to change my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close - you just need to start with the Player table, rather than the PlayerStatus, and use LEFT JOINs.

```
/* Select all Players and their Status */
SELECT ply.PlayerName, ply.PlayerTeam, sta.StatusDesc, pls.CreatedDate
FROM #Player ply
LEFT JOIN #PlayerStatus pls ON ply.PlayerID = pls.PlayerID
LEFT JOIN #Status sta ON pls.StatusID = sta.StatusID
LEFT JOIN #PlayerStatus pls2 ON pls2.PlayerID = pls.PlayerID AND pls2.PlayerStatusID > pls.PlayerStatusID
WHERE pls2.PlayerStatusID IS NULL
ORDER BY ply.PlayerID ASC;
```

Your original query started with PlayerStatus, and linked out from there, so it started with just those values that existed in the PlayerStatus table.

You were also using `INNER JOIN`s, which limit your results to only those records which match.  Using a `LEFT JOIN` instead (or a `RIGHT JOIN`, I suppose, but I find it easier to read with a `LEFT JOIN`) will allow you to retrieve all records from the first table, regardless of whether they have a match in the second table.  [See here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-joins)

Comment: That was quick! Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help. If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.